# I am attempting to paste emails in SharePoint from one column to another, however only some of the emails populated in the other column

Tags: gridview, copy-and-paste

The names are connected to email addresses and when I go to paste them in another column they do not populate.

The column setting is Person/Group so that the email will show up. It is weird how some populate and other cells are left blank after exiting grid view.

However when still in edit grid view mode, everything populates.